# When the Value_Changed called the text in the segment is align to vertical in android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, segment

I am using SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin for both iOS and Android.
I am facing a strang issue for Android. Initially the text on the segments is properly aligned but Value_Changed event is fired the text on the segment is aligning to the vertical.

Here is my code:

```
<segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControl ValueChanged="SegControl_ValueChanged" x:Name="SegControl" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TintColor="#0d2241" SelectedSegment="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControl.Children>
                                <segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControlOption VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Test" />
                                <segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControlOption VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Sample" />

                            </segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControl.Children>
                        </segmentedcontrols:SegmentedControl>
```

Here is the event

````
```public async void Handle_ValueChanged(object o, int e)  {  switch (e)  {  case 0:  MainPageContainer.Children.Clear();  MainPageContainer.Children.Add(TestView);       break;  case 1:  MainPageContainer.Children.Clear();  MainPageContainer.Children.Add(SampleView);    break;  }  }```
````

[image]

[image]

I dont have any such issues for iOS.

Here is how Iam facing the issue

Comment: Looks like the plugin has not been updated in a while, so probably a bug in the plugin maybe caused by updates in the XF framework. I don't think you will have much luck other than debugging the plugin code yourself

Comment: Thanks for the response @GeraldVersluis. I will look in to that

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT, No, I just removed the package and placed buttons in stack layout whose orientation is horizontal.